# Вывести 2 разные таблицы в одну средствами php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_data` (

    `id_user` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
    `surname` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `midname` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `gender` INT(1) NOT NULL,
    `date_of_birth` DATE NOT NULL,
    INDEX `FK_user_data_users` (`id_user`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_user_data_users` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `users` (

    `id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `login` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `pass_hash` VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Нужно вывести  2 таблицы в одну. Сразу скажу, что с sql плоховато у меня ( еще учусь). Если вывести с запросом : `SELECT * FROM users,user_data` в СУБД все красиво получается, но если в php переводить каждый `id` из `users` повторяется `n` количество раз с значениями из второй таблицы( `n` - количество строк во второй таблице)

Comment: SELECT * FROM users u join user_data ud on u.id_user = ud.id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в СУБД у вас также будет полное произведение таблиц, как и в пхп, а не "все красиво".

Вариант 1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users AS u
   , user_data AS d
WHERE u.id = d.user_id
```

Вариант 2:

Использование оператора join

```
SELECT * 
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN user_data AS d ON (d.user_id = u.id)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, человечище) 1й вариант подошел вроде. Пойду на сайт пробну запилить

Answer (score 0):

можно вывести с следующего `SQL` запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM users,user_data WHERE users.id=user_data.user_id
```